# I am getting error while running an R code for brand perception analysis using text mining

Tags: r, r-markdown, aggregate

While running this code in RMarkdown format for Brand Perception Analysis using text mining and visualization techniques, I am getting error in Sentiment analysis - plot by date section.

````
# Sentiment analysis - plot by date - understanding cummulative sentiment score movement

```{r}
mysentimentvalues <- data.frame(get_sentiment(tweet_en_df$text))
colnames(mysentimentvalues)<- "polarity"
mysentimentvalues$date <- tweet_en_df$created_at
result <- aggregate(polarity ~ date, data = mysentimentvalues, sum)
result
```
````

Below is the error.

> Error in aggregate.data.frame(mf[1L], mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : no
>   rows #to aggregate Calls:  ... aggregate ->
>   aggregate.formula -> #aggregate.data.frame Execution halted

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Complete code of the problem.

````
```{r}
library(readxl)
library(tm)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(wordcloud)
library(topicmodels)
library(syuzhet)
```


```{r}
tweet_df <- read.csv("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/BA/Text Analytics/Assignment/Tweets.csv")
```



# Convert tweets from factor to char and created date from factor to correct date format


```{r echo=FALSE}
tweet_en_df<-subset(tweet_df,tweet_df$lang=='en')
tweet_en_df$created_at <- as.Date(tweet_en_df$created_at,format= "%m/%d/%y")
#tweet_en_df$created_at <- as.Date(tweet_en_df$created_at,format, tryFormats = c("%m/%d/%y"))

tweet_en_df$text <- as.character(tweet_en_df$text)
str(tweet_en_df)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

**Cleaning the text data by removing links, tags and delimiters.**

```{r}
mycorpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(tweet_en_df$text))
writeLines(strwrap(mycorpus[[1]]$content))
```


```{r}
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus,content_transformer(tolower))
removeurl <- function(x) 
gsub("http[^[:space:]]*", "", x)
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, content_transformer(removeurl))
writeLines(strwrap(mycorpus[[5]]$content,60))
```


```{r}
removeUsername <- function(x) gsub("@[^[:space:]]*", "", x)  
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, content_transformer(removeUsername))
writeLines(strwrap(mycorpus[[5]]$content,60))
```


```{r}
myStopWords<- c((stopwords('english')),c("will","via","new","foldi","2019","samsung's","phone"))
mycorpus<- tm_map(mycorpus,removeWords , myStopWords)
writeLines(strwrap(mycorpus[[5]]$content,60))
```


```{r}
removeSingle <- function(x) gsub(" . ", " ", x)   
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, content_transformer(removeSingle))
writeLines(strwrap(mycorpus[[5]]$content,60))
```


```{r}
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus,removePunctuation)
writeLines(strwrap(mycorpus[[5]]$content,60))
```


```{r}
myCorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus,stripWhitespace)
writeLines(strwrap(mycorpus[[5]]$content,60))
```


```{r}
length(myCorpus)
```


Finding the term which is being used most frequiently

```{r}
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(mycorpus)
tdm
```


```{r}
freq.terms <- findFreqTerms(tdm,lowfreq = 35)
freq.terms
```


# Used to replace words with the proper ones

```{r}
replaceWord <- function(corpus, oldword, newword)
{
 tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(gsub), pattern=oldword, replacement=newword)
}
mycorpus<- replaceWord(mycorpus, "samsung's", "samsung")
mycorpus<- replaceWord(mycorpus, "samsungs", "samsung")
```

# Term frequency calculation

```{r}
term.freq<- rowSums(as.matrix(tdm))
term.freq<- subset(term.freq,term.freq>30)
df30 <- data.frame(term=names(term.freq),freq=term.freq)

term.freq<- subset(term.freq,term.freq>40)
df40 <- data.frame(term=names(term.freq),freq=term.freq)
df40
```


# Plotting the graph of frequent terms

```{r}
p30=ggplot(df30, aes(reorder(term, freq),freq)) + theme_bw() + geom_bar(stat = "identity")  + coord_flip() +labs(list(title="Term Frequency @30", x="Terms", y="Term Counts")) 

p40=ggplot(df40, aes(reorder(term, freq),freq)) + theme_bw() + geom_bar(stat = "identity")  + coord_flip() +labs(list(title="Term Frequency @40", x="Terms", y="Term Counts"))

grid.arrange(p30,p40,ncol=2)
```

#Plotting the word cloud

```{r}
word.freq <-sort(rowSums(as.matrix(tdm)), decreasing= F)
pal<- brewer.pal(8, "Dark2")
wordcloud(words = names(word.freq), freq = word.freq, min.freq = 10, random.order = F, colors = pal, max.words = 150)
```

#Find association

```{r}
list1 <- findAssocs(tdm,"smartphone",0.2)
corrdf1 <- t(data.frame(t(sapply(list1,c))))
corrdf1
```


# Topic Modeling to identify latent/hidden topics using LDA technique

```{r}
dtm <- as.DocumentTermMatrix(tdm)

rowTotals <- apply(dtm , 1, sum)

NullDocs <- dtm[rowTotals==0, ]
dtm   <- dtm[rowTotals> 0, ]
#NullDocs$dimnames
#NullDocs$dimnames$Docs
length(NullDocs$dimnames$Docs)
```


```{r}
if (length(NullDocs$dimnames$Docs) > 0) {
tweet_en_df <- tweet_en_df[-as.numeric(NullDocs$dimnames$Docs),]
}

lda <- LDA(dtm, k = 5) # find 5 topic
term <- terms(lda, 7) # first 7 terms of every topic
(term <- apply(term, MARGIN = 2, paste, collapse = ", "))
```


# Sentiment analysis

```{r}
emotions <- get_nrc_sentiment(tweet_en_df$text)
emo_bar<- colSums(emotions)
emo_sum <- data.frame(count=emo_bar,emotion=names(emo_bar))
emo_sum$emotion<- factor(emo_sum$emotion,levels = emo_sum$emotion[order(emo_sum$count,decreasing = TRUE)])
```

# Visulaize the emotions from NRC sentiment

```{r}
library(plotly)
```



```{r}
plot_ly(emo_sum,x=~emotion,y=~count,type = "bar",color =~emotion) %>%
  layout(xaxis=list(title=""),showlegend=FALSE,title="Twitter Sentiment Analysis")
```



# Sentiment analysis - plot by date - understanding cummulative sentiment score movement

```{r}
mysentimentvalues <- data.frame(get_sentiment(tweet_en_df$text))
colnames(mysentimentvalues)<- "polarity"
mysentimentvalues$date <- tweet_en_df$created_at
result <- aggregate(polarity ~ date, data = mysentimentvalues, sum)
result
```


# Plot the curve

```{r}
plot(result,type="l")
```



#Sentiment analysis - plot by date - understanding cummulative sentiment score movement




```{r}
result1 <- aggregate(polarity ~ date, data = mysentimentvalues, mean)
result1
```



# Plot the curve

```{r}
plot(result1,type="l")
```
````

Comment: Error appears clear, you do not have rows to aggregate (i.e., *mysentimentvalues* is empty). Check `get_sentiment()` call.

Comment: What would be helpful is a minimum complete verifiable example.  That would mean   removing everything that is not relevant to the problem you are asking about (e.g. the plots ).  Get just enough code to show the problem.  Also, please use a data set that other people can use.  Perhaps use sample data from one of the packages.  Where is it that date comes from?

Comment: Oh I see about dates but  still get_sentment() is not something you apply to a vector, it is used to choose a lexicon.

Comment: @Parfait .. can you please tell me the code to add the aggregate function.

Comment: You do have `aggregate`. Just the data is empty. We cannot see any data to verify. Check these variables on yur end, specifically the return of function I mentioned.